# How size of executable(.exe) affected using a static library which created compiling more source files in which some of them are not required for exe?

Tags: linker, static-libraries

High level problem statement was explained in the header. Let me put the question with a simpler example as below.
Lets say, I have created a static library(staticLib.a) using source files(A.c, B.c, C.c...Z.c).
This static library(staticLib.a) was used to create a final executable(./finalExe).
Final executable(./FinalExe) will use functions in A.c, B.c only at one instance.

So, My question is,

1. **Does rebuilding static library(staticLib.a) will really helps me in reducing the size of a final executable(./FinalExe)?**
2. **(or) Linker will take responsibility of linking the required functions in A.c and B.c in static library(staticLib.a), and manages the final executable size dynamically? At another instance, final executable needs functions in D.c, E.c, in such case does linker would be able to manage the executable size dynamically?**

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: The linker will pick what is needed and leave the rest. Otherwise all C programs would have been about the same size, if the entire C runtime had been included.

Comment: I thought of the same.  But, I would like to confirm this. I couldn't find it in a direct search.

Comment: Static libraries don't affect executable size at all, they're just archives of objects and as such, whether you link a library or objects separately, your executable will be exactly the same size in ideal scenario. If size matters that much, better look into your project structure and using `-O2` instead of `-O3` or even straight up `-Os` to make the most out of it, because `-O3` sacrifices size for speed when it can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker will pull object files (not sources) from `staticLib.a` as needed. Rebuilding the library to include fewer objects is not necessary.

Detailed description [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) or [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180627210132/http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).